# Экранирование двойных кавычек во всех атрибутах

Tags: php, html

Есть html-документ. Как экранировать все двойные кавычки внутри всех атрибутов документа?
Например атрибут `data-ft="{"tn":"K"}"` должен быть заменен на `data-ft="{\"tn\":\"K\"}"`.
Пробовал это делать с помощью регулярного выражения, но возникла проблема определением границ содержимого атрибута.

Answer (score 2):

Экранировать значения атрибутов нужно не слешами:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('{"tn":"K"}');
// {&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}
```

```js
let json = document.querySelector('span')
  .getAttribute('data-json');

let parsed = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(json);
console.log(parsed);
```

```html
<span data-json="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}">
  Something
</span>
```

Comment: {"tn":"K"} я дал для примера. содержимое атрибутов может быть разным.

Comment: Неважно, каким будет содержимое атрибутов. Корректное экранирования для html-представления - функция `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: Но я же не могу экранировать весь html. будет вот такое `data-ft=&quot;{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}&quot;`

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите чинить уже сломанный документ вместо того, чтобы изначально генерировать корректный? Это стоило добавить в вопрос. Откуда Вы получаете такие "документы"?

Comment: Именно, хочу чинить сломанный документ. Редактора копипастят текст с других сайтов. И вместе с текстом прилетают различные хтмл теги. Была идея парсить все теги и атрибуты, которые можно вставить в статью и потом формировать чистые без мусора. Но это очень громоздкий пласт работы.

Comment: Дело в том, что приведенный фрагмент не является валидным html, в общем случае задачу не решить. Можно только наделать костылей, опираясь на имеющийся в распоряжении пул "документов"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80695/discussion-between-evgenii-zaets-and-vp-arth).

Answer (score 0):

`data-ft="<?=json_encode('{"tn":"K"}')?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Костыли для решения задачи исправления сломанного документа должны опираться на предположения(в общем случае задачу решить невозможно).
Например, предположение, что в атрибутах не может быть пробелов:

```js
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}

{
  let doc = `
<p data-id="id="1";" data-ft="{"tn":"K"}">
  "Content"
</p>
<div some="valid" other="inva"lid">
  <span some="valid" other="inva"lid">"""""</span>
</div>`;
  let fixed = doc.replace(/(<\S+\s)([^>]+)(>)/g, function(full, before, attrs, after) {
    let escapedAttrs = attrs.replace(/([^=\s]+=")(\S+)(")/g, function(full, before, argV, after) {
      let escaped = escapeHtml(argV);

      return `${before}${escaped}${after}`;
    });
    return `${before}${escapedAttrs}${after}`;
  });

  document.querySelector('result').innerHTML = fixed;
}
```

```html
<result></result>
```